# How to make image and text align with checkbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, checkbox, multi-select

I have created a multiselectlist that included a stackpanel and with images and text that each correspond to a checkbox control. My implementation works correctly, although I cannot get the image and text to align correctly with the checkbox! I was wondering if there was a better way than simply adjusting the margins, but if not how could this be accomplished?

MainPage.xaml

```
<toolkit:MultiselectList x:Name="connectionTypeMultiSelectList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tap="connectionTypeMultiSelectList_Tap">
                        <toolkit:MultiselectList.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,0,0,0">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="35" Height="35" Margin="0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  Margin="10"/>
                                </StackPanel>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </toolkit:MultiselectList.ItemTemplate>                            
                    </toolkit:MultiselectList>
```

Comment: Since you are using data binding, I am unable to reproduce your result. Please provide a screenshot of your current result.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of the stackpanel and specify the image to fit and text as TextAlign=Center.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following margin values in your design and let me know if it works or not. It worked for dummy data which I created. I hope it works for you too.

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,0,0,0">
        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="35" Height="35" Margin="0,-12,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="12,5,0,0"/>
  </StackPanel>
```